# modifying a char pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

So i'm trying to build a function that takes a *char and reverses it. The function takes two parameters (N is the length of string)

```
void reverse_str(char *str, int N){
    char temp;
    temp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[N-i];
    str[N-i] = temp;
    if (i == N)
    {
        return;
    }
    i++;
    reverse_str(*str, N);
}
```

but for some reason when the compiler gets to the third line of the code; `str[i] = str[N-i];` it returns pointer empty `'\0'`

Is it possible to modify str without making a copy? did i do any kind of wrong declaration?

BTW `i` is a global value that is equal to 0 and increases every time the function is called recursively.

Comment: "N is the length of string". That means that `str[N-0]` is always the NUL. Because by definition a C string has the NUL character as the last character which is at the `strlen` index.

Comment: `while (N > 1) { swap(&str[0], &str[N-1]); N -= 2; str++; }` might do it.

Answer (score 1):

Do N = N -1 
before calling function as first step. That will solve the problem.

if N is length, any char_array[N] will be '\0' since it is end character. (basically string terminator). You want to operate on everything before \0 , but not including it.

Comment: Consider `char x[] = ""; int N = strlen(x); N = N-1; reverse_str(x, N);`  Better to let  `reverse_str()` handle the `-1` as needed.

Comment: I actually changed it and it works when i == 0 but when it increases it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the third line. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you calling it with a string literal? A string literal denotes an unmodifiable array (more precisely, attempting to modify it has undefined behavior).